regex with letters followed by a range of numbers
My strings look like:
DEMO10Q3, DEMO10Q4,DEMO11Q1,DEMO11Q2,DEMO12Q3,DEMO13Q4,...
The first number is year and the second number is quarter.
I want DEMO10Q3, DEMO10Q4, and all the ones from 2011 to 2024 such as DEMO11Q1,DEMO11Q2,DEMO12Q3,DEMO13Q4.
list.files(pattern = "^DEMO.*10Q[3-4].txt" | paste0("^DE.*", 11:24, "Q.*\\.txt", collapse="|"), recursive = T,full.names = F)

I got an error message:
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types

What's the right regex?

I do not understand. You simply want all elements of your character vector after DEMO10Q3? Is it ordered?

You could possibly just get a list of all the "^DEMO" values and then subset to x[x >= "DEMO10Q3"] since you have a numeric ordering in your text strings with the year and quarter components.

This is an important edit (and what I expected). Agreed, just index the output of list.files().

You could probably just get a list of all the "^DEMO" values and then subset afterwards, since you have a numeric ordering in your text strings with the year and quarter components:
x <- list.files(pattern="DEMO\d{2}Q[1-4]", recursive=TRUE)

## should result in something like:

x <- c("DEMO10Q1", "DEMO10Q2", "DEMO10Q3", "DEMO10Q4",
       "DEMO11Q1", "DEMO11Q2", "DEMO12Q3", "DEMO13Q4",
       "DEMO14Q1", "DEMO14Q2", "DEMO24Q2", "DEMO24Q3",
       "DEMO24Q4", "DEMO25Q1")

Then subset to the range you want:
x[x >= "DEMO10Q3" & x <= "DEMO24Q4"]
## [1] "DEMO10Q3" "DEMO10Q4" "DEMO11Q1" "DEMO11Q2" "DEMO12Q3" "DEMO13Q4"
## [7] "DEMO14Q1" "DEMO14Q2" "DEMO24Q2" "DEMO24Q3" "DEMO24Q4"

Logic seems to work with this example, since 2025 and earlier 2010 quarters were dropped:
setdiff(x, x[x >= "DEMO10Q3" & x <= "DEMO24Q4"])
##[1] "DEMO10Q1" "DEMO10Q2" "DEMO25Q1"


@thelatemail's answer is probably more appealing, but if you really want to do it with a regex, ^DEMO(10Q[34]|(1[1-9]|2[0-4])Q[1-4]) is what you are looking for:
> xxx <- expand.grid("DEMO", 10:25, "Q", 1:4) |> apply(1, paste0, collapse = "")
> xxx
 [1] "DEMO10Q1" "DEMO11Q1" "DEMO12Q1" "DEMO13Q1" "DEMO14Q1" "DEMO15Q1" "DEMO16Q1"
 [8] "DEMO17Q1" "DEMO18Q1" "DEMO19Q1" "DEMO20Q1" "DEMO21Q1" "DEMO22Q1" "DEMO23Q1"
[15] "DEMO24Q1" "DEMO25Q1" "DEMO10Q2" "DEMO11Q2" "DEMO12Q2" "DEMO13Q2" "DEMO14Q2"
[22] "DEMO15Q2" "DEMO16Q2" "DEMO17Q2" "DEMO18Q2" "DEMO19Q2" "DEMO20Q2" "DEMO21Q2"
[29] "DEMO22Q2" "DEMO23Q2" "DEMO24Q2" "DEMO25Q2" "DEMO10Q3" "DEMO11Q3" "DEMO12Q3"
[36] "DEMO13Q3" "DEMO14Q3" "DEMO15Q3" "DEMO16Q3" "DEMO17Q3" "DEMO18Q3" "DEMO19Q3"
[43] "DEMO20Q3" "DEMO21Q3" "DEMO22Q3" "DEMO23Q3" "DEMO24Q3" "DEMO25Q3" "DEMO10Q4"
[50] "DEMO11Q4" "DEMO12Q4" "DEMO13Q4" "DEMO14Q4" "DEMO15Q4" "DEMO16Q4" "DEMO17Q4"
[57] "DEMO18Q4" "DEMO19Q4" "DEMO20Q4" "DEMO21Q4" "DEMO22Q4" "DEMO23Q4" "DEMO24Q4"
[64] "DEMO25Q4"

> grep("^DEMO(10Q[34]|(1[1-9]|2[0-4])Q[1-4])", xxx, value = TRUE)
 [1] "DEMO10Q3" "DEMO10Q4" "DEMO11Q1" "DEMO11Q2" "DEMO11Q3" "DEMO11Q4" "DEMO12Q1" "DEMO12Q2" "DEMO12Q3" "DEMO12Q4"
[11] "DEMO13Q1" "DEMO13Q2" "DEMO13Q3" "DEMO13Q4" "DEMO14Q1" "DEMO14Q2" "DEMO14Q3" "DEMO14Q4" "DEMO15Q1" "DEMO15Q2"
[21] "DEMO15Q3" "DEMO15Q4" "DEMO16Q1" "DEMO16Q2" "DEMO16Q3" "DEMO16Q4" "DEMO17Q1" "DEMO17Q2" "DEMO17Q3" "DEMO17Q4"
[31] "DEMO18Q1" "DEMO18Q2" "DEMO18Q3" "DEMO18Q4" "DEMO19Q1" "DEMO19Q2" "DEMO19Q3" "DEMO19Q4" "DEMO20Q1" "DEMO20Q2"
[41] "DEMO20Q3" "DEMO20Q4" "DEMO21Q1" "DEMO21Q2" "DEMO21Q3" "DEMO21Q4" "DEMO22Q1" "DEMO22Q2" "DEMO22Q3" "DEMO22Q4"
[51] "DEMO23Q1" "DEMO23Q2" "DEMO23Q3" "DEMO23Q4" "DEMO24Q1" "DEMO24Q2" "DEMO24Q3" "DEMO24Q4"

So no 10Q1, 10Q2, or anything after 2024, but everything in between.
